# Adding data to table by comparing one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am working to split apart this one large table into smaller tables for easier management via foreign keys, and have come across a dilemma with trying to bring the data back together. I am new to working with this type of data merging so I am a bit lost.

There are 3 tables: one table with a list of product owners, one table with a list of systems they are responsible for, and the original table with all of the data (examples below):

```
Product Owners Table:
+----+---------------+
| id | product_owner |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | User1         |
+----+---------------+
PRIMARY KEY: id

System Table:
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | system    | product_owner |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  6 | Server1   |          NULL |
+----+-----------+---------------+
FOREIGN KEY: product_owner(id)

Original Table:
+---------+---------------+
| system  | product_owner |
+---------+---------------+
| Server1 | User1         |
+---------+---------------+
```

I want to take the data from the original table and merge it with the new system table, however I don't want to go the route of multiple `UPDATE` statements to add what needs to be added. What's the best route to approach on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch more poking around and reading additional terminology, I was able to solve my problem by using a mix of `join` statements in conjunction with `update`, `set` and `where` statements:

```
   update system_table a
    join original_table.system b
        on a.system = b.system
    join product_owner c
        on c.product_owner = b.product_owner
set a.product_owner = c.id
where c.product_owner = b.product_owner;
```

Comment: Looks good. Remember, you can accept your own answer after a period of time has elapsed.